# What is the right approach to this object initialization problem?

Tags: java

I'm pretty new to Java. I'm learning object instantiation. I am solving this problem which says to create a program that only creates/instantiates an odd number of objects. It won't instantiate if the number of objects is an even number. What is the right approach to this problem? Do I create the objects and then compare and see whether the number of objects is odd/even? Or do I create a condition that only allows an odd number of inputs of objects? Which one is the appropriate right approach to the problem?

Also, if I instantiate the objects using an array, will using array[i] = null in a for loop delete the created objects? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `array[i] = null` won't necessarily detele the created objects, unless if it was the only reference variable pointing towards that object.

Comment: I believe later approach of "creating a condition that only allows an odd number of inputs of objects" is suitable

Comment: @AbhiN Would using a for loop and an array with an if condition satisfy the required condition? Is there any other way to create multiple odd number of objects other than using a for loop/array or typing them manually?

Comment: @AAW Yes, you can use that approach

Comment: @AbhiN okay. Thanks. Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

> I am solving this problem which says to create a program that only
>   creates/instantiates an odd number of objects.

Is this what you want? This creates only 1 object... which is odd number.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  var _ = new int[0];
}
```

> Also, if I instantiate the objects using an array, will using array[i]
>   = null in a for loop delete the created objects?

No. It will just lose the reference to the object. Garbage Collection will delete the object when it decides it is right time to do so.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Instead of typing in an odd number of objects manually, can't we like put a for loop in there that creates only an odd number of objects using arrays? Would that be the right way or is there a better way to do it (other than typing an odd number of objects ourselves)?